# Parse json key value pair in Rails to format the date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to format date by iterating through the `@data` json formatted input shown as below.

```
 @data= JSON.parse(request,symbolize_names: true)[:data]

 @data   = @data.each{ |key,val| k = Date.parse(key).strftime("%Y %m") }
```

But this way it is showing error "no implicit conversion of Symbol into String". 
Could any one please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're iterating over a hash where the keys are symbols, then the error is telling you where and what's the problem. In order to parse a date, you must pass a string as argument, and as you haven't converted such object, then you're getting the error.

Try using `to_s`, to convert the symbol to string:

```
@data.each do |key, _|
  puts Date.parse(key.to_s).strftime '%Y %m'
end
```

Note if you're inside a block, and you're not going to use the `k` variable you're creating, then you can avoid creating it, it won't be available outside the block. You're just printing the parsed date.

If you're not going to use the `value` block variable, then you can omit it.

As pointed @mu, you can omit the `symbolize_names: true`, and this way the keys will be strings, then, the conversion isn't needed:

```
require 'date'
require 'json'

request = '{
  "data": {
    "2017-11-22 00:22:26": "foo" ,
    "2017-11-22 00:22:27": "bar" 
  }
}'
@data = JSON.parse(request)['data']
@data.each do |key, _|
  puts Date.parse(key).strftime '%Y %m'
end
```

`request` is an approximation to your real data.

Comment: Or just don't `symbolize_names: true` and leave the keys as strings since they're going to be processed as strings anyway. And `@data = @data.each { ... }` does nothing useful because `each` returns its receiver.

Comment: I want to format the date on the go and store into the same object. Is that possible? @SebastianPalma

Comment: Try using `@data.map` instead each `parsed_data = @data.map { |key, _| Date.parse(key).strftime '%Y %m' }; parsed_data`, is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, Thanks. The error was that when 'symbolic_name: true' was removed it returned nilclass for my scenario.

Comment: You have to access the data key as a string key instead a symbol one, because keys are no more symbols :) @Wings2fly.